# Error inflating Fragment contains 2 child Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

My SoundFragment.java: (stackoverflow warns me, why?)

```
public class SoundFragment extends Fragment {
    TabHost tabHost;
    Activity activity;
    public static SoundFragmentBGM bgmFragment;
    public static SoundFragmentSoundEffect soundEffectFragment;
    private static int count =1;
    public static SoundFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SoundFragment fragment = new SoundFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    public SoundFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // View initialization
        GCLog.d("Hideaki", "STARTING INFLATE VIEW OF SOUND ==" + count++);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sound, container, false);

        initSoundStackManager(view);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                if (tabId.equals("BGMtab")) {
                    soundEffectFragment.onStopMedia();
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                } else {
                    bgmFragment.onStopMedia();
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    void initSoundStackManager(View view) {
        tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.soundtabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        //create BGMtab
        View viewBGM = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.tab_bgm_layout, null);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BGMtab").setIndicator(viewBGM).setContent(R.id.tabBGM);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //create 効果音tab
        View viewSoundEffect = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.tab_kokaon_layout, null);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("効果音tab").setIndicator(viewSoundEffect).setContent(R.id.tabSoundEffect);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        if (bgmFragment == null) {
            bgmFragment = new SoundFragmentBGM();
            GCLog.d("Hideaki", "INSTALL BGMFRAGMENT");
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.gc_sound_bgm_fragment, bgmFragment);
        if (soundEffectFragment == null) {
            soundEffectFragment = new SoundFragmentSoundEffect();
            GCLog.d("Hideaki", "INSTALL soundEffectFragment");
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.gc_sound_effect_fragment, soundEffectFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        //set default tab
        if (SoundFragmentSoundEffect.se_mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        } else {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        HomeActivity.soundLoaded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(soundEffectFragment);
        ft.remove(bgmFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

My fragment_sound.xml, where contain 2 child fragments.

```
> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     tools:context="jp.porthy.getclub.fragment.SoundFragment">
> 
>     <TabHost
>         android:id="@+id/soundtabhost"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
> 
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:orientation="vertical">
> 
>             <TabWidget
>                 android:id="@android:id/tabs"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:showDividers="none"
>                 android:layout_height="38dp" />
> 
>             <FrameLayout
>                 android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
> 
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:id="@+id/tabBGM"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                     android:orientation="vertical">
> 
>                     <FrameLayout
>                         android:id="@+id/gc_sound_bgm_fragment"
>                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
> 
>                     </FrameLayout>
>                 </LinearLayout>
> 
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:id="@+id/tabSoundEffect"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                     android:orientation="vertical">
> 
>                     <FrameLayout
>                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                         android:id="@+id/gc_sound_effect_fragment">
> 
>                     </FrameLayout>
>                 </LinearLayout>
>             </FrameLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </TabHost>
> 
> </LinearLayout>
```

My logcat error:

> ```
> 07-14 16:20:47.893  28471-28471/jp.porthy.getclub W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aaf210)
> 07-14 16:20:47.903  28471-28471/jp.porthy.getclub E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c00d9 for fragment SoundFragmentBGM{420d43b8 #1 id=0x7f0c00d9}
>             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:822)
>             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
>             at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
>             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
>             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

I try to add delay time after loading view and after destroying view but it can solve my problem.
Error when i attach and detach SoundFragment repeatedly.

Please help me debug, thank you very much.

Comment: can you please check in your R.java file whether there is entry for 0x7f0c00d9. Most probably this entry is not present.

Comment: looks like problem is in `SoundFragmentBGM` fragment. show it's code and xml layout

Comment: i don't think problem in SoundFragmentBGM fragment.
Error when i attach and detach SoundFragment repeatedly.
I think it crashed when old SoundFragmentBGM isn't detached and i try attaching new one.
Correct me if i wrong, thank a lot.

Comment: in R.java:
public static final int gc_sound_bgm_fragment=0x7f0c00d9;